# Change font-awesome arrow submenu

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, submenu

I would like to change the font-awesome to `fa-angle-down` on submenu opened and put back `fa-angle-left` on submenu collapsed.

HTML and CSS:

```css
.sidenav li .arrow:before {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#SubMenuTools" class="collapsed">
    <a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> External Tools <span class="arrow pull-right fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>
</li>
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="SubMenuTools">
    <li><a href="">First tool</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Second Tool</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to? Should it be in CSS or in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `transform` paired with a `transition`. This will create a nicer effect than using JS to simply replace `.fa-angle-left` with `.fa-angle-down`.

```css
.sidenav li .arrow {
  transition: transform .25s;
}

.sidenav li.collapsed .arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Have a look at this pen: http://codepen.io/ptrkcsk/pen/PbGbXW

Comment: Yes, pure CSS solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery:

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var expanded = $('#SubMenuTools').hasClass("in");
  if (expanded == true) {
    $('#arrow').removeClass("fa-angle-down");
    $('#arrow').addClass("fa-angle-left");   
  }
  else {
    $('#arrow').removeClass("fa-angle-left");
    $('#arrow').addClass("fa-angle-down");   
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav li .arrow:before {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#SubMenuTools" class="collapsed">
  <a href="#/">
    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> 
    <span>External Tools</span> 
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id='arrow'></i>
  </a>
</li>
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="SubMenuTools">
  <li><a href="">First tool</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Second Tool</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following JQuery sample.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var expand = false;
  $("#mainMenu").click(function() {
    expand = !expand;
    if (expand) {
      $(this).children("span").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-angle-down");
    } else {
      $(this).children("span").removeClass().addClass(" fa fa-angle-left");
    }
  });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/bhavbyav/)